# stage getHeight does not include decorations

Tags: javafx

I've been trying to set the `minWidth` and the `minHeight` of the scene in the `start()` method, after calling `show()`, but it seems the `getHeight()` call does not include the decorations as it is supposed to. The height of the stage is the same as the root scene.

The doc suggests that this should not be the case. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent r = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("things.fxml"));
        Scene root = new Scene(r);

        primaryStage.setTitle("foo");
        primaryStage.setScene(root);

        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();

        primaryStage.show();

        // primaryStage.getHeight() and root.getHeight() are the same here!
        // doc suggests that they are supposed to be different

        primaryStage.setMinWidth(primaryStage.getWidth());
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(primaryStage.getHeight());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is explained in the documentation is correct, you may have misunderstood. I explain according to what is written in there, and according to the mistakes that you made in your code, **another thing I use windows so it may be due to your OS** :

`sizeToScene()` method :
*Set the width and height of this Window to match the size of the content of this Window's Scene.* We understand that your `stage` will have the same size as your scene, and you have not defined a size to your scene,so it takes just the size properties of its contents `Parent/FXML`.

```
Parent r = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("things.fxml"));
Scene root = new Scene(r);  //Size not defined
```

Which explains the size defined in the last two methods `setMinWidth/setMinHeight`. Here you only give almost the same value (**+16 width and +38 height Those of decoration**) to your `stage`

```
primaryStage.setMinWidth(primaryStage.getWidth()); //return the same width as Scene+16
primaryStage.setMinHeight(primaryStage.getHeight()); //return the same height as Scene+38
```

[image]

If, for example, the `Parent/FXML` size is (600x400), the `getWidth()` method of the stage will return (616) and `getHeight()` (438). I hope this will help you solve your problem, good luck !

Comment: The problem is that I don't seem to get the +16 width and +38 height that you seem to get from the decoration. Might be an OS thing.

Comment: I've never used Ubuntu, or at least programmed on it, so I can't be sure that this is the cause !

Comment: Probably is, I just loaded a root with a specific width and height and checked the dimensions, the decorations were not included when I called show which is not spec behavior. Could also be a bad jdk install. Oh well.